# Looking for short horror story about graveyard and family of ghouls

Tags: story-identification, horror

I read this story in the 1990s.

- A little boy goes into a graveyard and meets a woman.
- He goes into a crypt. This is house of ghouls. The boy is in fact a ghoul(!).
- The boy's father collected finger bones
- There was a girl with black hair and a little bat woven into her hair.
- The woman from the graveyard goes into crypt. **The boy mesmerizes her and his family eat the woman.**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a book by Caitlin R. Kiernan. There are ghoul families like this in her "Daughter of Hounds" trilogy.

Maybe she has written short fiction in the same setting?

Comment: Thank you, I'll check, but Kiernan first published in 1995. I think I read this story in the early 1990s. In any case, thank you.